# VyOS: Failure to commit after L2TPv3 configuration

Tags: routing, tunnel, l2tp, virtual, vyos

I am trying to get familiar with VyOS (using a VM) and while working on L2TPv3 I encountered something strange: after configuring the L2TPv3 interface and try to commit, an error occurs as if the interface cannot be created! Any help?

```
vyos@vyos# sh interfaces l2tp
+l2tpv3 l2tpeth0 {
+    bridge-group {
+        bridge br0
+    }
+    destination-port 10000
+    encapsulation udp
+    local-ip 172.31.31.2
+    peer-session-id 1
+    peer-tunnel-id 1
+    remote-ip 172.30.30.2
+    session-id 1
+    source-port 10000
+    tunnel-id 1
+}
[edit]
vyos@vyos# commit
[ interfaces l2tpv3 l2tpeth0 ]
RTNETLINK answers: Network is unreachable
RTNETLINK answers: No such device
Cannot find device "l2tpeth0"

[[interfaces l2tpv3 l2tpeth0]] failed
Commit failed
[edit]
vyos@vyos#
vyos@vyos#
```

Comment: OK, it turned out that the version I was using is no longer supported! using the latest stable release I managed to achieve the L2TPv3 tunnel and pass traffic through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K, it turned out that the version I was using is no longer supported! using the latest stable release I managed to achieve the L2TPv3 tunnel and pass traffic through it.